# Get value of json key in razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, json.net

How to get a variable value from a json object after deserialization?

Example below:

**Data**

```
{
    "test": "test_data",
    "visible": true,
    "other": "test 2"
}
```

**HTML**

```
@{
    var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Model.Value);

    ??? data["other"]???
}
```

I want to get the value that belongs to the key other.

Comment: Don't put login like deserialization etc. into your views, prepare the data in a viewmodel and pass this to the view in a ready-to-consume structure

Comment: Thxs for advice, i moved it to the viewmodel ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() you could deserialize the string as a dynamic type and then access it as usual :

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Model.Value);
string other = data.other;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thxs, that helped! Didn't know about the dynamic option.